# How do I find the second endpoint of a chord of an ellipse

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, conic-sections

Given an ellipse with center at the origin with equation x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 =1, how do I find the second endpoint of a chord of length L that begins at (a,0)? Yes, there are two but they will be symmetric about the x axis. Thanks. I am trying to simplify a surveying issue to lay out a quarter ellipse by placing two pins, one at (0,0) and the other at (L,0) and measuring radii from equal chord lengths along the perimeter.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

You want to intersect the ellipse whose equation is

$ \dfrac{x^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{b^2} = 1 , \hspace{25pt}  a \gt b $

with the circle

$ (x - a)^2 + y^2 = \ell^2 $

where $ \ell \le 2 a $

Solve for $y^2$ from the second equation,

$y^2 = \ell^2 - (x - a)^2 $

substitute this into the first equation, it becomes

$ \dfrac{x^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{1}{b^2} ( \ell^2 - (x - a)^2 ) = 1 $

collect terms,

$ \bigg( \dfrac{1}{a^2} - \dfrac{1}{b^2} \bigg) x^2 + \bigg( \dfrac{2 a}{b^2} \bigg) x + \bigg( \dfrac{ \ell^2 - a^2 - b^2 } { b^2 }\bigg) = 0 $

Solving using the quadratic formula, you get a valid solution and an extraneous solution.  Taking the valid solution $x$ you can directly compute the corresponding values of $y = \pm \sqrt{ \ell^2 - (x - a)^2 } $